# Can replacing the wifi card of a laptop make it out of action?

Tags: asus-laptop, wireless-card

I am thinking to replace wifi card of my Asus x552cl-sx029h notebook. The current card is mt7630e (I never changed it).

I want to change my current card with an Intel 7260hmw AN wireless card

Can this change put my notebook out of action? I mean electrical problems.

Answer (score 1):

Both cards use PCIe and therefore operate in the same voltage range. There shouldn't be any electrical change, except that your new card seems to manage electricity better. Although this is only my opinion and I don't make any conclusions nor am I responsible for any possible damage.